# "Disabled" option for choiceField - Django

Tags: django

I having trouble with a simple question : 
How to have some "disabled" field in a dropdown menu generated via a modelForm and choiceFied in the django Framework ?

At the moment, I cannot figure out how to obtain such an output :
-- Root 1 entry -- (disabled)
-- Elt 1 -- (not disabled)
-- Root 2 entry -- (disabled)

Do you have any advice ?

Pierre

Comment: This is still an open issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16149

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Django's form widgets offer a way to pass a list of attributes that should be rendered on the `<option>` tag:

```
my_choices = ( ('one', 'One'), ('two', 'Two'))
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=my_choices, 
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))
```

Unfortunately, this won't work for you because the attribute will be applied to EVERY option tag that is rendered. Django has no way to automatically know which should be enabled and which should be disabled.

In your case, I recommend writing a custom widget. It's pretty easy to do, and you don't have that much custom logic to apply. The docs on this are [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances). In short though:

- subclass `forms.Select`, which is the default select renderer
- in your subclass, implement the `render(self, name, value, attrs)` method. Use your custom logic to determine if the `value` qualifies as needing to be disabled. Have a look at the very short implementation of `render` in `django/forms/widgets.py` if you need inspriation.

Then, define your form field to use your custom widget:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=my_choices, 
                                   widget=MyWidget)
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but the proper method to change the options' attributes is `render_option()` not `render()` (which renders the whole widget)

Comment: And remember to implement corresponding field validation too. Just disabling an option in HTML isn't enough if you don't want the option to be used.

Comment: This offers a good start, though I've greatly expanded on this answer in my solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673199/disabled-option-for-choicefield-django/55348111#55348111

Answer (score 13):

You can create Choices as mentioned by Bryan like this. In the below options Root 1, Root 2 are automatically disabled and they will look like Group Options

```
CHOICES = (
  ('-- Root 1--', 
      (
        ('ELT1', 'ELT1'),
        ('ELT2', 'ELT2'),
        ('ELT3', 'ELT3'),
      )
   ),
  ('-- Root 2--', 
      (
        ('ELT3', 'ELT3'),
        ('ELT4', 'ELT4'),
      )
  ),
)
```

The above option will display like this. In the below image, Root 1 and Root 2 are not selectable.

[image]

Hope this will clear your problem

-Vikram

Answer (score 8):

```
field_choices = (
        ('','Make choice'),
        (1,'first'),
        (2,'second'),
        (3,'third')
    )

from django.forms import Select

class Select(Select):
    def create_option(self, *args,**kwargs):
        option = super().create_option(*args,**kwargs)
        if not option.get('value'):
            option['attrs']['disabled'] = 'disabled'

        if option.get('value') == 2:
            option['attrs']['disabled'] = 'disabled'

        return option
```

Comment: great solution, only thing I changed was `option['attrs']['disabled'] = True` as this makes the attribute appear with no assigned value e.g just `disabled` not `disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 7):

This might be a late answer but this is a simplified version that can be modified using the form instance.

You can either pass a list of values to be disabled i.e

```
def __init__(self, disabled_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        self.disabled_choices = disabled_choices
```

OR

```
from django.forms import Select


class SelectWidget(Select):
    """
    Subclass of Django's select widget that allows disabling options.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._disabled_choices = []
        super(SelectWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def disabled_choices(self):
        return self._disabled_choices

    @disabled_choices.setter
    def disabled_choices(self, other):
        self._disabled_choices = other

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
        option_dict = super(SelectWidget, self).create_option(
            name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=subindex, attrs=attrs
        )
        if value in self.disabled_choices:
            option_dict['attrs']['disabled'] = 'disabled'
        return option_dict
```

To disabled an option based on a condition i.e user isn't a superuser.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=SelectWidget, choices=(('on', 'On'), ('off', 'Off')))

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['status'].widget.disabled_choices = ['off']
```

Comment: Excuse me I don't understand what is "Status" in "choices=Status.choices()"

Comment: This is a helper function for managing choice values using IntEnum or Enum types https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html blog post https://blog.richard.do/2014/02/18/how-to-use-enums-for-django-field-choices/

Answer (score 4):

It seems django 1.1 will allow "optgroup": [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
        ('Audio', (
                ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
                ('cd', 'CD'),
            )
        ),
        ('Video', (
                ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
                ('dvd', 'DVD'),
            )
        ),
        ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
    ])
```

This imho is a must have.

Answer (score 4):

Simple questions sometimes have complex answers in Django. I spent a lot of time getting this to work well. Combining Jarrett's overview with an important note from jnns about `render_option` and some help from #django on freenode I have a well-working complete example solution:

First, this example assumes a normally defined choices-type CharField in a model I call Rule. I subclass my own `TimeStampedModel` but you can use a `models.Model`:

```
class Rule(TimeStampedModel):

    ...

    # Rule Type
    SHORT_TERM_RULE = 'ST'
    MAX_SIGHTINGS_PER_PERIOD_RULE = "MA"
    WHITE_LIST_RULE = "WL"
    BLACK_LIST_RULE = "BL"
    RULE_CHOICES = (
        (SHORT_TERM_RULE, 'Short Term Rule'),
        (MAX_SIGHTINGS_PER_PERIOD_RULE, 'Max Sightings Per Period Rule'),
        (WHITE_LIST_RULE, 'White List Rule'),
        (BLACK_LIST_RULE, 'Black List Rule'),
    )
    rule_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=RULE_CHOICES,
        default=SHORT_TERM_RULE,
    )

    ...
```

In forms.py, define the widget subclassing `Select` that accepts `disabled_choices`. It has a custom `render_option()` that adds `disabled` to the html output of option tags if their choice is included on the passed in `disabled_choices` list. Note, I left most of the `render_option()` code from `Select` as-is:

```
class MySelect(Select):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), disabled_choices=()):
        super(MySelect, self).__init__(attrs, choices=choices)
        self.disabled_choices = disabled_choices

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        if option_value is None:
            option_value = ''
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''
        for key, value in self.disabled_choices:
            if option_value in key:
                return format_html('<option disabled value="{}"{}>{}</option>', option_value, selected_html,
                                   force_text(option_label))
        return format_html('<option value="{}"{}>{}</option>', option_value, selected_html, force_text(option_label))
```

Then, in defining the form subclassing `ModelForm`,  check for a passed-in `disabled_choices` list and initialize the field accordingly. In this example, I also sneak in a default choice.

```
class RuleChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = ['rule_type']

    # Add a default choice to the list defined in the Rule model
    default_choice = ('DF', 'Choose a Rule Type...')
    choices = list(Rule.RULE_CHOICES)
    choices.insert(0, default_choice)
    choices = tuple(choices)

    rule_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=MySelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, disabled_choices=[]),
                                  choices=choices)

    def __init__(self, *args, disabled_choices=None, **kwargs):
        super(RuleChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if disabled_choices:
            self.fields['rule_type'].widget.disabled_choices = disabled_choices
```

Then in your view, define `disabled_choices` as a list, appending choices from your `_CHOICES` var in your model and pass it into the form instantiation. In my logic, I use list comprehension of `RULE_CHOICES` to get the tuple of the choice I want to disable. Though there may be a simpler way, please feel free to post suggestions to simplify or improve this answer.

```
    disabled_choices = []
    # Logic disabling choices
    if Rule.objects.filter(route=route, rule_type=Rule.SHORT_TERM_RULE).exists():
        disabled_choices.append([item for item in Rule.RULE_CHOICES if Rule.SHORT_TERM_RULE in item][0])
        disabled_choices.append([item for item in Rule.RULE_CHOICES if Rule.MAX_SIGHTINGS_PER_PERIOD_RULE in item][0])

    rule_choice_form = RuleChoiceForm(disabled_choices=disabled_choices)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create a menu in which the list items are separated into categories, and you don't want the categories themselves to be selectable?

If so, you can achieve this by having your template render the field using  tags, e.g.

```
<select name="my_field" id="id_my_field">
<optgroup label="-- Root 1 entry --">
    <option value="1">Elt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Elt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Elt 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="--- Root 2 entry ---">
    <option value="4">Elt 4</option>
    <option value="5">Elt 5</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to do this using JavaScript.

Add the following line of code to the HTML page that containts your select element:

```html
    <script>
        document.querySelector("select").options[0].disabled = true;
    </script>
```

And if you want to disable an option in multiple select elements in your page you can do the following:

```js
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(function(element) {
            element.options[0].disabled = true;
        });
    </script>
```