# How to customise attributes of forms.Select options in Django

Tags: python, django, select, widget

I am working on a custom requirement which demands to customise select option attributes. My dropdown will show the list of options, and some of those options should be shown as disabled as per certain conditions.

[image: List of options along with disabled options]

I have tried customising the `Select widget attributes` by passing `disabled = disabled`. But that disables the whole dropdown. By looking into the code of django 1.11.5, it seems that the attributes applied on Select will be applied to its options.

Can anyone please suggest how this functionality can be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: There is a general solution which works for Django 2.+ and allows to add a title and other things in options, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097149/1788851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can sub-class the `django.forms.widgets.Select` widget, passing new parameter `disabled_choices` to its `__init__` function and override the `create_option` method like this:

```
class MySelect(Select):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), disabled_choices=()):
        super(Select, self).__init__(attrs, choices=choices)
        # disabled_choices is a list of disabled values
        self.disabled_choices = disabled_choices

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
        option = super(Select, self).create_option(name, value, label, selected, index, subindex, attrs)
        if value in self.disabled_choices:
           option['attrs']['disabled'] = True
        return option
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really a great help. I could get it working after doing some minor alterations :-)

Comment: I have defined a complete example of this using a ModelForm here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673199/disabled-option-for-choicefield-django/55348111#55348111