# Disabled option in Django Select Widget using ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.11

I am trying to show inactive users as "disabled" in my form's Select widget.

I have a worker who is a django user model.

### models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True,related_name='worker')
```

It is represented by a ModelForm, using a subclass to display the full name of the user.

### forms.py

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.get_full_name()

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    worker = UserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=1).order_by('first_name'),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['worker']
```

Currently, the filter is_active=1 means that inactive users simply don't show in the list and where they've already been selected it appears as "---".

My ideal would be they appear but are greyed out so they are presented but can't be selected.

From reviewing https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2453/

Which I found in
["Disabled" option for choiceField - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673199/disabled-option-for-choicefield-django)

I was able to conclude that the subclass of the select should work. However I can't tell how to get between the queryset and the widget in order to achieve the expected result. Reading suggests the render method on the widget might be the way but I couldn't find examples of how to pass the information or exactly where create_option is invoked.

Comment: I have written out a complete solution to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673199/disabled-option-for-choicefield-django/55348111#55348111