# Django Forms: How to set choose select option class and set disabled or selected in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible in a simple way?
I have in my forms Class

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    
    CHOICES = (('Option 1', 'Option 1'),
               ('Option 2', 'Option 2'),)
    
    widgets = {
               'classification': forms.Select(choices=CHOICES, 
                                              attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
              }
```

but i want to have

```
<select>
 <option class="some-class" value="option 1" disabled>option 1</option>
 ...
</select>
```

How to add a class in `options` and also `disabled`?

Comment: You can make your own `Select` as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369360/4151233

Comment: thanks i don't know how I missed that post.